# fancybox change content into modal window

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'd like to change the content of a div inside a fancybox, I have this in my html page:

inline div for fancybox:

```
<div id="user_should_subscribe" style="display:none;">
  <div id="test">hi</div>

</div>
```

need to show fancybox automatically when page is loaded:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  $("#user_should_subscribe").fancybox({
    content: $("#user_should_subscribe").html()
  }).trigger("click");
  // -->
  </script>
```

so far so good. fancybox is shown but if I try to change the content of div#text the content does not change. Inside the fancybox I have a ajax form, when the request is completed I trigger

```
$("#test").html('new')
```

but nothing change, but if I try to check the content in this way

```
$("#test").html('new')
alert($("#test").html('new'))
```

I get: **new** so I think the problem is related to fancybox because the div#test content is not rendered correctly, any hint?
Thank you

Comment: can you create Bin of your code on site Codebins.com?

Comment: how do you trigger with click on `user_should_subscribe` if that div has `style="display:none;"`?

Comment: I dont know why but i changed div#test with div.test and it works fine, maybe I had more istance of div#test in my page. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not opening element having ID "user_should_subscribe", but you are creating and opening its clone (using .html() method), so you are now having two identical elements having the same ID. That`s why your code later would change only first one.

So, you need to open your element as "inline". For example (this would open once) -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fancybox.open({
            href : "#user_should_subscribe",
            type : 'inline'
        });
    });
</script>
```